# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when put file in hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I use `subprocess.popen` in `python` to put files in hdfs. it runs accurately using python on the Windows `cmd`. but as I use vscode to run the code, I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  Error.

```
hdfs_path = os.path.join(os.sep,'mongo_import_export')

#put csv into hdfs 

put = Popen(['hadoop','dfs','-put','mongo-hadoop/import_export.csv','/mongo_import_export'], stdin=PIPE,bufsize=-1)

put.communicate()
```

Knowing that my file `import_export.csv` is in the file in witch the code is located and mong-hadoop folder is in my local files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode is running the code in a different working directory than your local CMD. Use the absolute path to the files you want to put rather than relative paths.